# Conditional probability or compound Poisson process?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

Arrivals of passengers at a bus stop form a Poisson process ${N(t), t ≥ 0}$ with rate $\lambda = 2$ per unit of time. Assume that a bus departed at time $t = 0$ leaving no customers behind. Let $T$ be the arrival time of the next bus. Then, the number of passengers present when it arrives is $N(T)$. Suppose that the bus arrival time $T$ is independent of the Poisson process and that $T ∼ U[0,1]$. By first conditioning on $T$, determine the mean and the variance of the number of passengers present when the next bus arrives.

I'm kind of confused on how to start this. I can't quite figure out if this would be a conditional probability where we apply Bayes Theorem to $E[N(t)|t=T]$ or if this is actually a compound Poisson process. If it is a compound Poisson process I'm not quite sure how to set that up.

Comment: Again this law of total probability will come up very often when you study the materials about Poisson process: $\displaystyle E[N(T)] = \int_0^1 E[N(T)|T = t]f_T(t)dt$ (the integration limit is simplified to $[0, 1]$ due to the given distribution of $T$). Actually it is also equivalent to law of total expectation: $E[N(T)] = E[E[N(T)|T]]$. You can do the similar trick on the variance - law of total variance.

Comment: Okay, so using the law of total probability for expectation I would get $\int_{0}^{1} E[N(T)|T=t] dt$ as $f_{T}(t)$ is equal to $1$. I'm thinking $E[N(T)|T=t] = E[N(t)]$ as that's how I think the probability would be treated using Baye's Theorem, is that correct?